# MVC4: jQuery Validation Unobtrusive Native working incorrectly

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

My MVC4 web app is built on Umbraco 7. I have installed the following nuget packages:

```
jQuery 1.10.2
jQuery.Validation 1.11.1
jQuery.Validation.Unobtrusive.Native.MVC4 1.1.0.0
```

The unobtrusive validation is from this website: http://jqueryvalidationunobtrusivenative.azurewebsites.net/Home/GettingStarted

My view looks like this:

```
<form id="frmContact" method="post" action="@Url.Action("ContactForm", "ContactFormSurface")">
<div>
    <label>Full Name</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FullName, true)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FullName, "*")
</div>
<div>
    <label>Company</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Company, true)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Company, "*")
</div>
<div>
    <label>Email Address</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EmailAddress, true)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.EmailAddress, "*")
</div>
<div>
    <label>Message @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Message, "*")</label>
    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message, true, 10, 30, new { @class = "input-xl" })
</div>
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "Please correct the following errors before submitting the message")
<div>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</div>
</form>
```

In the web.config:

```
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

My model:

```
public class ContactFormViewModel
{
    [Required, Display(Name = "Full Name")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public string Company { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(?!\.)(""([^""\r\\]|\\[""\r\\])*""|([-a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~]|(?<!\.)\.)*)(?<!\.)@[a-z0-9][\w\.-]*[a-z0-9]\.[a-z][a-z\.]*[a-z]$", ErrorMessage="Not a valid email address")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the scripts (which I have confirmed loads correctly in the browser)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

The rendered HTML looks like this (at initial page load):

```
<form action="/umbraco/Surface/ContactFormSurface/ContactForm" method="post" id="frmContact">
<div>
    <label>Full Name</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="FullName" id="FullName" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="The Full Name field is required." class="input-validation-error">
    <span data-valmsg-replace="false" data-valmsg-for="FullName" class="field-validation-error">*</span>
</div>
<div>
    <label>Company</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="Company" id="Company">
    <span data-valmsg-replace="false" data-valmsg-for="Company" class="field-validation-valid">*</span>
</div>
<div>
    <label>Email Address</label>
    <input type="text" value="" name="EmailAddress" id="EmailAddress" data-rule-required="true" data-rule-regex="{&quot;pattern&quot;:&quot;^(?!\\.)(\&quot;([^\&quot;\\r\\\\]|\\\\[\&quot;\\r\\\\])*\&quot;|([-a-z0-9!#$%&amp;'*+/=?^_`{|}~]|(?&lt;!\\.)\\.)*)(?&lt;!\\.)@[a-z0-9][\\w\\.-]*[a-z0-9]\\.[a-z][a-z\\.]*[a-z]$&quot;}" data-msg-required="The Email Address field is required." data-msg-regex="Not a valid email address" class="input-validation-error">
    <span data-valmsg-replace="false" data-valmsg-for="EmailAddress" class="field-validation-error">*</span>
</div>
<div>
    <label>Message <span data-valmsg-replace="false" data-valmsg-for="Message" class="field-validation-error">*</span></label>
    <textarea rows="10" name="Message" id="Message" data-rule-required="true" data-msg-required="The Message field is required." cols="30" class="input-validation-error input-xl"></textarea>
</div>
<div data-valmsg-summary="true" class="validation-summary-errors"><span>Please correct the following errors before submitting the message</span>
        <ul>
            <li>The Full Name field is required.</li>
            <li>The Email Address field is required.</li>
            <li>The Message field is required.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<div>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</div>
</form>
```

As you might see, the validation text is already at an invalid state at load time (before any keypresses or form submissions). Also, when I submit the empty form it submits back to the server, so client side validation doesn't actually happen. The jQuery validation scripts run, since the company field is not required and is reflected so in the validation message's class attribute (`'field-validation-valid'`)

**EDIT**:
Controller code as requested:

```
    public class ContactFormSurfaceController: Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult ContactForm(ContactFormViewModel model)
        {
            return PartialView("ContactForm", new ContactFormViewModel());
        }
    }
```

Can anybody help me out here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show us your controller code?

Comment: inspect your browser and let me know is there any error of javascript or jquery

Comment: @heymega: sure, I have included it in the post.

Comment: @Dilip0165: Using FireBug, no errors detected.

Comment: Is `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()` still required?

Comment: @SoonDead: It doesn't say so on the project website, but I've just tried removing it -> it removes the inline validation errors, but the summary is still showing the errors. Tried removing `@Html.ValidationSummary()` as well, and as expected, it clears all the errors, but the form still submits even when empty.

Comment: I have also upvoted this question as I have never heard of this nuget package but now that I have read about it I'm considering migrating some of my projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this new Native Unobtrusive validation, you seem to have to call `.validate()` on the form manually.

From the [Date Demo Example](http://johnnyreilly.github.io/jQuery.Validation.Unobtrusive.Native/Demo/Date.html):

```
$("form").validate({
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        alert("This is a valid form!")
    }
});
```

Or in simpler examples:

```
$("form").validate();
```

I have no experience with this, but since this only uses the jQuery Validation Plugin, the [Documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/) might be worth to read.

This **WORKS** with your generated HTML:

See these fiddles for reference:

http://jsfiddle.net/4JE62/

http://jsfiddle.net/4JE62/1/

Comment: From the Unobtrusive Native website: "Oh, and remember that you no longer need to serve up the jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js on a screen where you are using jQuery Validation Unobtrusive Native." http://jqueryvalidationunobtrusivenative.azurewebsites.net/Home/GettingStarted

Comment: @SoonDead I think these are alerady part of the jQuery.Validation.Unobtrusive.Native.MVC4 nuget package.

Comment: HAHAHA true. I have no experience with Native, deleting my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but unfortunately to no avail. I thought that I did call that line of code, but when looking for it in the HTML source it wasn't there (apparently Umbraco Surface Controllers don't render MVC sections). Anyway, added it now, but still the same. Also tried only calling the `.validate()` method on form submission, but not working. Maybe hold of migrating your projects just yet. :)

Comment: Got it! A combination of all of your helpful suggestions as well as changing the `$("form").validate();` line to `$("#formId").validate();`. For some reason multiple forms on one page breaks this. http://jsfiddle.net/4JE62/3/ Thanks for the help

Comment: Hi Guys,  Just wanted to let you know that the documentation has migrated to GitHub pages now: http://johnnyreilly.github.io/jQuery.Validation.Unobtrusive.Native/

Comment: @JohnnyReilly thanks for keeping my answer up to date, this library of yours is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

dont use validate(), use valid() instead

```
$("#frmId").valid()
```

Remember to include validate.unobtrusive.js in your page

Comment: No, the answer above solved it. validate.unobtrusive.js is not required when using Native Unobtrusive validation (as seen on their website and mentioned in OP). And `validate()` is the correct function (not `valid()`) it simply had an issue when there were two forms on the page, so my jQuery selector found them both, instead of just the one I'm trying to validate.

Comment: I don't know, actually i go to this page because i try to solve my problems when call validate() and it don't work. and after that. i find solution and just want to share.
May be my jquery is difference version with you

Comment: Actually its confusing just for others if someone is stopping the form on ajax call use the valid method and validate method must be called on document ready.