# how to validate textbox and textarea using jquery in MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, validation, textbox, jtextarea

I Have View

```
<input type="text" class="form" name="abc" id="abc" placeholder="Enter text">
 <textarea class="form" id="xyz" rows="3"></textarea>
```

I want to put validation on this text box and text area
I have js file `validation.js`
I am sending data on button through Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            //alert('worked');
            $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    cache: false,
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.Action("SubmitHome", "Admin")",
                    data: {
                        "abc": $("#abc").val(),
                        "xyz": $("#xyz").val(),

                    },
                    success: function (data) {

                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert('Failed to retrieve states.');
                    }
                });
            });


                });
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Now I do not understand how i will apply **validation.js** on textbox and textarea. And i want to use only this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can add validation attributes to the view model properties in mvc and this will apply data attributes for validation on the form. Then in the button click you can do the following:
(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee256141(VS.100).aspx)

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
    if($("#formid").validate()){
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("SubmitHome", "Admin")",
            data: {
                "abc": $("#abc").val(),
                "xyz": $("#xyz").val(),

            },
            success: function (data) {

            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve states.');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Alternatively you could enable unobtrisive ajax and a normal form submit would do client side validation and not require any extra js.

[MVC4: jQuery Validation Unobtrusive Native working incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21043184/mvc4-jquery-validation-unobtrusive-native-working-incorrectly)

Comment: I do not want to use HTML helper. I just want to learn how can i use this jquery on the textbox and textarea

Comment: Any particular reason that you need to do it this way or is it just to know a different way of doing it? Another way of doing it could be to use this: http://jqueryvalidation.org/ . Or bind a method to check the value of the textbox or text area on change.

Comment: I am in the middle of project now i cann't change it.